# TSQL query to filter configuration dates list

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, logic

How should i form a query if i wanted dates/records from the below table such that Year is greater than or equals 2012 and Month is greater than September.

This query does not work it brings Months 2012 (7,8, 9,10,11,12) , 2013(1 upto 12) which is not right because i wanted to see 2012(9,10,11,12) 2013( 1 upto 12). It is including 7 and 8 th month of 2012 Year

```
select * from ConfigurationDate
where Year >= 2012 OR ( Year = 2012 AND Month >= 9 )
Order By Year,Month ASC
```

**Table Schema**

```
DateId INT Auto Inc

Year INT

Month INT
```

**Dummy Data**

```
DateId           Year        Month
1                2012          7

2                2012          8

3                2012          9

4                2012          10

5                2012          11

6                2012          12

7                2013          1

8                2013          2

9                2013          3

10               2013          4

11               2013          5

12               2013          6

13               2013          7

14               2013          8

15               2013          9

16               2013          10
```

Comment: Ok I seem to have figured it out. Will put up an answer just in few seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually thinking of it, i don't need to include the 2012 date in First where condition again since it is covered by second condition. So the answer is below

```
select * from ConfigurationDate
where Year > 2012 OR ( Year = 2012 AND Month >= 9 )
Order By Year,Month ASC
```